# using WSHttpBinding, by default is that secure?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service, which was initially setup using BasicHttpBinding, but someone suggested I switch over to WsHttpBinding, as that's more secure.  I see there is a way to setup the security feature of WsHttpBinding, but I was wondering is it already secured by default?  Are the messages that go from my service already encrypted in some format, if so does anyone what security/algorithm is used, as we need to provide a document for the project and is security is used need to let them know which one.

thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The WsHttpBinding will use Message security by default, which means that your message (payload) is encrypted and signed per the [WS-Security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Security) specification. However, you can add more security on top of this by using Transport security with an SSL certificate. Microsoft has a pretty [detailed article on Message Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733137.aspx), which you should definitely read.